# Lucene: query parser is not working as expected

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I'm using Lucene.Net but I'm sure it still aplies for the non.Net flavour.

This is my query:

```
Collection:drwho AND Format:"Blu-ray"
```

This is what the query parser does to it:

```
{+Collection:drwho +Format:"blu ray"}
```

This is clearly not what I am after. This is the code I'm using:

```
Dim analyzer = New StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29)
Dim qp = New QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, Nothing, analyzer)
Dim q As Query = qp.Parse(query)
```

Any ideas on why the query is being butched? According to http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_4_0/queryparsersyntax.html, I cannot for the life of me see what is wrong with my query...

Comment: What do you _expect_ it to do?

Comment: Well...work:). Turns out the search doesn't work when documents are added with Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `NOT_ANALYZED` fields either you should create `TermQuery` in your code or use `KeywordAnalyzer` since it requires exact matching of the term in the index and in your query(your input is stored as `Blu-ray` in the index) where other analyzers processes the input and converts `Blu-ray` to `blu ray` for example, as you have already noticed.

If you change your field to `ANALYZED` and use StandardAnalyzer while indexing, your query would also work in current form.